# Angular UIRouter cancel/abort resolves

Tags: angular-ui-router, resolve

I've been using the powerful ui-router with angular and have used the resolve functionality extensively. In my application, I have the following state:

```
.state('main.client', {
       abstract:   true,
       url:         '/:clientID',
       controller:  'ClientDetailsController',
       templateUrl: 'client_details.html',
       resolve:     {
            client: function ($stateParams, ClientService) {
                        return ClientService.getClient($stateParams.clientID) 
                    },
            invoices: function ($stateParams, client, InvoiceService) {
                        return InvoiceService.getInvoices($stateParams.clientID) 
                    },
 }
```

The resolves result in http requests.

Now it is quite feasible for the user to click through multiple clients until they get to the client they are interested in. In my testing, the resolves for client and invoices are queued even though they may no longer be relevant for the current client.
I would like to be able to cancel/abort these extraneous http requests. I have used the following aborting logic previously http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2616-aborting-ajax-requests-using-http-and-angularjs.htm but as the ui-router waits for the resolve to complete, I don't know how to hook in.
Has anyone had any succes here?

Answer (score 0):

If you say a user can decide to go from one client to the next without seeing the client info (-> before the resolves are 'resolved') then "resolve" at the state level is the wrong tool to load data for you in this specific case.

I suggest moving those async calls to the ClientDetailsController and assign the results to the $scope in .then() of the returned promised.

So the user flow is not blocked by the resolves, with the consequence that the user gets to see a ClientDetail-Page where the data is not yet fully loaded. Just use appropriate placeholders.

With this a user can switch quickly between different clients and the data is loaded only when he stays at one client.

Comment: Reto, thanks for your suggestion. I was looking at this type of approach prior to using ui-router. In this case, I'll look at presenting a partially loaded view to the user, allowing them to navigate away to a sibling view. Loading the data into the scope when the controller loads will help facilitate this

Comment: It is quite simple: only use resolve if you want to wait for the data to be loaded before the page gets visible, this is the only eason why we have the "resolve" feature. If you don't want to wait, load data in the controller. Please consider accepting/upvoting the answer if it helps you - this is how Stackoverflow works.